# What happens to uncommitted files if I accidentally set my svn depth to immediates or empty?

Tags: svn, depth

I'm a regular user of svn, and I take full advantage of the shallow checkout "depth" feature. However, I was on auto-pilot the other day and accidentally set the trunk of my local copy of the repo to a depth of "immediates." What happens to files with changes that are uncommitted (or even files that have not been added yet) in subfolders that have now been rendered "empty" at a much higher level?

Say I have this structure,

```
trunk/folder1/subfolder/subsubfolder/foo.txt
trunk/folder2/subfolder/bar.txt
trunk/folder3/subfolder/subsubfolder/red.txt
```

and foo.txt has an uncommitted change (M), bar.txt is unknown (?), and red.txt is committed. (Assume all folders, subfolders, and subsubfolders exist and are committed in the repo).
Then I set
`svn up --set-depth=immediates trunk`
Does svn pass over those `folder1/subfolder/subsubfolder/` and `folder2/subfolder`, and only deletes the local copy of `folder3/subfolder` (and everything beneath it)?

Further, if I want to "repair the damage" by setting the depth back to infinity, will things "just pick up right where they left off?"